# Why can't I access child node from body tag?

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

And I can't access div tag on body's child at [9] , [11]

I use bd.firstChild, bd.childNodes[n] before but null always appears

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="EUC-KR">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
  var rt = document.getRootNode();
  document.write(rt.nodeName + " "); //document
  var ht = rt.firstChild;
  document.write(ht.nodeName + " "); // html
  var hd = ht.firstChild;
  document.write(hd.nodeName + " "); // head
  var bd = hd.nextSibling;
  document.write(bd.nodeName + " "); // body
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
     <h1>1</h1>
     <h2>2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the HTML structure of the page?

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you and also note that you cannot use document.write after the page loads. Instead use console.log or innerHTML of some container

Comment: i edit my code can you guys still help me?

Comment: Your script runs before the document is ready. Put it just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @trincot, apologies. There was an edit I did not see.

Answer (score 0):

Before you edited the snippet to document.write before the document was completed, I created the code below -  you many NOT use document.write after the document is completed but you CANNOT show the tags/nodes before they are rendered:

It seems there is some strange going's on with just getting the nodes - Chrome adds a newline after the head before the body

This shows this issue

You want to check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <p></p>
  <script>
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter/acceptNode

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker


    var nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
      // Node to use as root
      document.querySelector('html'),

      // Only consider nodes that are text nodes (nodeType 3)
      NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,

      // Object containing the function to use for the acceptNode method
      // of the NodeFilter
      {
        acceptNode: function(node) {
          // Logic to determine whether to accept, reject or skip node
          // In this case, only accept nodes that have content
          // other than whitespace
          if (!/^\s*$/.test(node.data)) {
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
          }
        }
      },
      false
    );

    // Show the content of every non-empty text node that is a child of root
    var node;

    while ((node = nodeIterator.nextNode())) {
      console.log(node.tagName);
    }

    /* ----------- Older code ------------- */
    /*  
      
        var rt = document.getRootNode();
        console.log("Root", rt.nodeName + " "); //document
        var ht = rt.firstChild;
        console.log("Root's firstChild", ht.nodeName + " "); // html
        var HTML = ht.nextSibling;
        console.log("html's nextSibling", HTML.nodeName + " "); // HTML
        var HEAD = HTML.firstChild;
        console.log("Html's firstChild", HEAD.nodeName + " "); // HEAD
        var newLine = HEAD.nextSibling;
        var BODY = newLine.nextSibling;

        console.log("newLine's nextSibling", BODY.nodeName + " "); // BODY
    */
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thats to bad for nood like me

Comment: may i ask another? i can't find child node on body node, it always return null or textContent already write on browser

Answer (score 0):

- The browsers' web-page parser (and document-builder) is paused whenever a `<script>` element is encountered (assuming it doesn't have `async` or `defer` attributes).
- `document.write` causes the argument text to be added to the document stream immediately when invoked.

  - The argument text is appended to the currently parsed document text then fed into the document builder synchronously.

    - This synchronous behaviour, and the fact parsing text and creating document nodes from it is expensive, is why `document.write` is deprecated and its use discouraged.
- You are passing human-readable text into `document.write` so new `#text` nodes will be added immediately where the `<script>` element is, which is inside the `<head>` element.
- But all of that is irrelevant because in your case your `<html>`'s `firstChild` is actually a `#text` node comprised of the whitespace betwen `<html>` and `<head>`, the only way to eliminate this is by having `<html><head>` instead of `<html>(#text "\r\n\r\n")<head>`.
- `var bd` is not the `<body>` element. Use your debugger.
- Also, avoid using the `node`-based DOM API because it includes things like whitespace `#text` nodes and comments. It's usually better to use the `Element`-based DOM API instead.

Comment: thx for recommand better way i'll use that method after solve it